# I would like to prevent Excel VBA for checking for the existence of a procedure

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to prevent Excel VBA from checking for the existence of procedures before running.

I would like to run a programme like this:

```
VBProj.VBComponents.Import "C:\somefile.bas"  
Call sub_which_only_exists_after_the_above_import()
```

But I get the following:
"Compile Error
 Sub or function not defined"
and the "Call" line is highlighted.

I've searched google but not found anything helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers
Geoff.

Comment: Use `CallByName` or `Application.Run` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Set vbcomp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import("C:\somefile.bas")
 Application.Run vbcomp.Name & "." & "sub_which_only_exists_after_the_above_import"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I just needed to change `Call mySub(myParameter)` into `Application.Run "mySub", myParameter`